# how to use substr function in search

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, search-engine

i need to use substr to get the name who have written letters or if i write a part of the name

```
 if(isset($_GET['search'])){
 $sql="SELECT * FROM students WHERE first_name='".$_POST['sname']."' OR         last_name='".$_POST['fname']."'";
 $record=mysql_query($sql);}

<?php
echo"<form action='admin.php?page=3&search' method='Post'>";
echo"<input type='text' name='sname' value='ex: Student Name'> &nbsp; &nbsp;";
echo"<input type='text' name='fname' value='ex: Family Name'> &nbsp; &nbsp;";
echo"<button type='submit' name='search'   class='btn' >Search</button>";
echo"</form>";
?>
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: how to use substr function in search

Comment: from where you are taking the name?

Comment: what you need to do? do you need to check sname and fname entered or not?

Comment: if i write ahm get all names that have ahm

Comment: i think OP wants to search by part of name.. ?

Comment: Please vote and accept the answer which helpful to other viewers. @manao

Comment: Why did you use `first_name='".$_POST['sname']."'` It seems to me it should `first_name='".$_POST['fname']."'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the query, Use `LIKE` in the query:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM students WHERE first_name like '%".$_POST['sname']."%' OR last_name like '%".$_POST['fname']."%' ";
```

Comment: Updated. Thanks Ruchish Parikh :).

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE %`.

```
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
 $sql="SELECT * FROM students WHERE first_name LIKE '%".$_POST['sname']."%' OR last_name LIKE '%".$_POST['fname']."%'";
 $record=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Glade to help you. Please UV and accept the answer which helpful to other viewers. :) @manao